# How to properly "left join row or fallback" on a per row basis?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `task` holding non-translated fields:

```
CREATE TABLE task (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    reviewed    boolean         NOT NULL,
    author_id   bigint          /* NULLABLE */
);
```

The localized fields are stored in `task_l10n`:

```
CREATE TABLE task_l10n (
    task_id             bigint          NOT NULL REFERENCES task(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    locale              varchar(5)      NOT NULL,

    title               varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    description         varchar(500)    NOT NULL,
    some_other_col      varchar(100)    /* NULLABLE */,

    PRIMARY KEY (task_id, locale)
);
```

**I want to get all tasks by a set of ids together with their translations**.

To select the translations I want to use a **preferred locale**. If the task is not translated, I want to get the default translation.

For this I am building a function that I, for example, could call like this:

```
select * from get_task_l10n(array[1, 2, 3], 'en')
```

and it should, for example, return:

```
1   "de"    "task 1 title DE"   "task 1 desc DE "   "task 1 other DE"
2   "en"    "task 2 title EN"   "task 2 desc EN "   "task 2 other EN"
3   "de"    "task 3 title DE"   "task 3 desc DE "   "task 3 other DE"
```

After some hours I came up with this function that works with a **single** `task_id`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_task_l10n(p_task_id bigint, preferred_locale text) RETURNS TABLE (LIKE task_l10n) STABLE STRICT LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
  SELECT t.*
  FROM task_l10n t
  WHERE
    t.locale = (
      SELECT CASE WHEN
        (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM task_l10n
                 WHERE task_id = t.task_id
                    AND locale = preferred_locale
                )
        ) THEN preferred_locale
        ELSE 'de'
        END
    )
    AND t.task_id = p_task_id
$$;
```

I am then using it the function to left join on the main entity, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM task t
LEFT JOIN get_task_l10n(id, 'en') tl10n ON tl10n.task_id=t.id
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

### Question

When using the function in the left join (see last code snippet), I wonder about efficiency. From my understanding that function now is called on every row which feels like an **N+1** problem. How can I get rid of it?

---

Explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM task t
LEFT JOIN get_task_l10n(id, 'en') tl10n ON tl10n.task_id=t.id
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)

=>

"Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=8.73..53.49 rows=4 width=1075)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on task t  (cost=8.47..15.58 rows=3 width=91)"
"        Recheck Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on task_pkey  (cost=0.00..8.47 rows=3 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))"
"  ->  Function Scan on get_task_l10n tl10n  (cost=0.25..12.75 rows=5 width=984)"
"        Filter: (task_id = t.id)"
```

Comment: Side note: You should alias all tables and qualify all columns. Otherwise it's unnecessarily hard to keep track of what is what and one might more easily overlook a mistake.

Comment: And you should ask one question per post (or at least very close ones). Your two questions are very different.

Comment: And what do you mean by "call the function on its own"? That leaves a lot of room for interpretation. Show the relevant code.

Comment: I found the issue with the first part, it was a name clash of the parameter and the column name. I removed this and it is only about the n+1 now.

Comment: "*I wonder about efficiency.*" - did you look at the query plan already? Please post it.

Comment: @Bergi: thanks, yes it was a typo. Also, I added the EXPLAIN result

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions

Comment: @Abeliato how do I see if my function is inlined?

Comment: And: `SELECT t.* FROM task_l10n t WHERE t.locale in ('de', preferred_locale) order by case when t.locale = preferred_locale then 1 else 2 end limit 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support the query, you want an index on `task_l10n (task_id, locale)` (which should already be there as that's the primary key). With that the engine can look up if a row for a given `task_id` and `locale` exists very quickly. It also supports the outer query as it can also be used to quickly look up records for a given `task_id`. So you should be quite good here.

Comment: Could you elaborate if this suffers from n+1 ( `Nested Loop Left Join `) and if it would be better to define the function in a way that takes all ids as a parameter in a single call? I.e. `get_task_l10n(p_task_ids bigint[], ...`

Comment: @Stuck: What does suffering from "n+1" mean? But the index I suggested can also be used for the join of your other query. Additionally you want an index on `task (id)` (which again should already be there as that's the primary key) for that.

Comment: I mean by n+1 that the function to create the table for the join might be executed for every row instead of creating the table for joining once for all queried ids. I don't understand if this is a problem or not.

Comment: @Stuck: Check the link Abelisto provided in the comments to make sure your function can be inlined. But even if it isn't inlined, unless the set of tasks you query is huge (certainly way more than the three in your example), I don't think there is a large problem there, if it gets called for every such task. But of course inlining is better and possible here (Make sure about the declaration of `STABLE` or `IMMUTABLE` and not `STRICT`. At least in my tests the default was to declare `STRICT` which prevented inlining. But without `STRICT` it works for me.).